# Directive not called on input change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm facing an issue which I can't seem to solve.
I have several inputs with each a directive to validate the input value, like this:

```
<div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">last name</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.lastname.$invalid && (form.lastname.$touched || form.$submitted)}">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control"
                       model-blur
                       validator-lastname
                       ng-trim="true"
                       ng-model="fields.lastname.value"
                       ng-maxlength="fields.lastname.validation.maxLength">
                <input-group-addon class="input-group-addon"
                                       iga-char=""
                                       iga-form="form"
                                       iga-field="form.lastname"
                                       iga-if-touched="true">
                </input-group-addon> 
            </div>

            <form-message-list fml-form="form"
                                   fml-field="form.lastname"
                                   fml-label="Last name"
                                   fml-fieldData="fields.lastname">
            </form-message-list>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This field required the following pattern: `/^[\'a-zA-Z_]+( [\'a-zA-Z_]+)*$/`

My issue is this:
**When I add an invalid value to my input, like this: / , my invalid message remains and ng-invalid-pattern remains on my field.**

When I add this pattern to my field like this: `ng-pattern="/^[\'a-zA-Z_]+( [\'a-zA-Z_]+)*$/"` I don't have any issues. But when I try to validate via my directive **validator-lastname** it only checks one time. When I fill the input with an invalid value and then change it to empty, which is allowed, the ng-invalid-pattern error remains.

This is my directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('validatorLastname', validatorLastname);

/* @ngInject */
function validatorLastname() {

    var directive = {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

        var valid = false;

        var formatter = function (inputValue) {
            if (inputValue) {
                var res = inputValue.match(/^[\'a-zA-Z_]+( [\'a-zA-Z_]+)*$/);
                if (res && res.length > 0) {
                    valid = true;
                }

                modelCtrl.$setValidity('pattern', valid);
                valid = false;
            }
            return inputValue;
        };
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(formatter);
        if (scope[attrs.ngModel] && scope[attrs.ngModel] !== '') {
            formatter(scope[attrs.ngModel]);
        }
    }
}
```

I made a JSFiddle to reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sZZEt/537/

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need to bind the element to either an onChange event (if you want to validate for each keystroke) or onSubmit (of the form, if you want to validate on submit only)

Comment: Well, it actually does validate, but only when I enter an invalid value and then delete the value the error object does not get updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update your directive code to make everything work fine.

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('validatorLastname', validatorLastname);

/* @ngInject */
function validatorLastname() {

    var directive = {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

        var valid = false;

        var formatter = function (inputValue) {
            if (inputValue) {
                var res = inputValue.match(/^[\'a-zA-Z_]+( [\'a-zA-Z_]+)*$/);
                if (res && res.length > 0) {
                    valid = true;
                }

                modelCtrl.$setValidity('pattern', valid);
                valid = false;
            }else{
                modelCtrl.$setValidity('pattern', true);  
            }
            return inputValue;
        };
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(formatter);
        if (scope[attrs.ngModel] && scope[attrs.ngModel] !== '') {
            formatter(scope[attrs.ngModel]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a `plunk` for your problem... 
It is because if inputValue is null then your $setValidity method will not invoke and could not perform validation again. You should set pattern validity to true inside else part. if you want to make field valid for no-input.
You can now refer to updated plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/N3DrsB?p=preview

Comment: In the Punkr, if you enter an invalid value and then delete the value, the error object should dissapear because the field is then valid again. I made a fiddle to reproduce my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sZZEt/537/

Comment: Yes so i updated the plunker to understand your problem.

Comment: Oh it works! So simple, yet so affective! Guess I have some friday blues. ;-) Can you update your answer with the else statement for people with the same problem in the future?