# How to make a password include at least one special character?

Tags: angularjs

The password field should be more than 8 characters and include at least one special characters. How to meet the 'at least one special character' requirement in AngularJS?

```
<input type="password" name="pwd" data-ng-minlength="8" data-ng-model="user.pwd" />
```

[How to add password validation using regular expression in angularjs according to certain criterion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352562/how-to-add-password-validation-using-regular-expression-in-angularjs-according-t)

This question is very helpful to me, but my password requirement is slightly difference, like no number is allowed in my password, and I want to seperate the length requirement and special character requirement if possible so I can tell users what is the exact error. And I just wonder where can I learn how to set up ng-pattern? For me, they look like random characters...like this one:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add password validation using regular expression in angularjs according to certain criterion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352562/how-to-add-password-validation-using-regular-expression-in-angularjs-according-t)

Comment: You will need to make your own directive. [Angular Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)

Comment: That *random character* pattern is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with below code

```
var regularExpression = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;
```

With the above regex you can complete your task, for detail study of it go to the link :

https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp